# Get columns of 2D ndarray defined by index' in another 2D ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an ndarray `arr = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])` and an index-array

`arr_idx = np.array([[0,2],[1,2],[2,1]])` where each row in `arr_idx` corresponds to the index of `arr` which I want to have i.e the result should be `[[1,3],[5,6],[9,8]]`.

Can this be done using numpy-operations? I can do it using e.g listcomprehension, but it's some fairly large data that I have, thus if we can vectorize it, that would be better.

I have tried

```py
result = arr[arr_idx]
```

which results in

```
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [7, 8, 9]],
       [[4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]],
       [[7, 8, 9],
        [4, 5, 6]]])
```

which should've been `array([[1,3],[5,6],[9,8]])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
result = arr[np.arange(arr.shape[0])[:,None], arr_idx]
```

Or:

```
result = np.take_along_axis(arr, arr_idx, 1)
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 3],
       [5, 6],
       [9, 8]])
```